# NestJS - How to mock Scoped Packages?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

I've got a scoped package (which is mentioned [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules)), it looks like `@my-company/common`, but there are multiple modules imported, like `@my-company/common/dist/services/aws/s3`, `@my-company/common/dist/services/mongodb/atlas` and some of them are `@Injectable`, some a just non-injectable classes. How can I mock them in the e2e test which calls a controller, which calls a service, where these modules exist?

For clarity and for example: I've got service `MyAwsService` which looks like this:

```
import { MyS3Service } from '@my-company/common/dist/services/aws/s3';

@Injectable()
export class MyAwsService{
  private s3: MyS3Service;

  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {
    const configuration = {
      region: config.get('region'),
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: config.get('key'),
        secretAccessKey: config.get('secret'),
      },
    };
    this.s3 = new MyS3Service(configuration);
  }
}
```

When I run test I don't want to provide any credentials and just want to mock the whole `MyS3Service`. I've read in aforementioned jest documentation that I need to put `jest.mock()` somewhere on top of the test file, so I've put it under imports like:

```
jest.mock('../node_modules/@my-company/common/dist/services/aws/s3/s3.service.js');
```

and (following same documentation) created the file in folder like this: `__mocks__/@my-company/common.js`. For example it has only one function: `getListOfFiles()`, so inside this mock I have:

```
export const getListOfFilesFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 'OK' }));

export const MyS3Service = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
  return {
    getListOfFiles: () => {
      console.log(`mock getListOfFiles called`);
      return getListOfFilesFn;
    },
  };
});
```

Before this I had tests fail because s3 service requires credentials, now it seems to run OK, but the problem is: mocked `MyS3Service` doesn't return anything (and, actually, it doesn't log output just to see that it worked) in the service being tested. All responses are `undefined` and I can't understand: if my mock doesn't work - what actually works? If I remove `jest.mock()` from top of file test fails on the s3 init (because no credentials), if I keep it - test runs, but seems like test doesn't run MY mock. What it runs then?

Comment: OK, I've found what was wrong: 

1. I have a [non-default export](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports)

2. After that I removed everything in __mock__ folder and the mock started working. 

But not the way I expected. I can return **Promise.resolve({value: 'some value'})**, but I can't do a **mockImplementation** - it returns nothing at all. And I can't spy on the mocked functions

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the more-or-less correct version

first, created helper function, it may be put somewhere to test-utils or whatever other folder, and imported in the test:

```
export const S3ServiceMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    getListOfFiles: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 'OK' }))
  };
});
```

finally, mock with `requireActual` to have all other imports work as before, especially if you have many. Note the `named` export `S3Service`, which must be included in return with the same name it exists in `@my-company/common`, which means I imported it with `import {S3Service} from '@my-company/common';`

```
jest.mock('../node_modules/@my-company/common', () => {
  const originalModules = jest.requireActual('../node_modules/@my-company/common');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModules,
    S3Service: S3ServiceMock,
  };
});
```