# How to spy on named class import mock from node_modules?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

This is the second part of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893170/nestjs-how-to-mock-scoped-packages), first part I've solved.

I've got a scoped package (which is mentioned [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules)), it looks like `@my-company/common` in `node_modules`. And I've got service `MyAwsService` which looks like this:

```js
import { MyS3Service } from '@my-company/common';

@Injectable()
export class MyAwsService{
  private s3: MyS3Service;

  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {
    const configuration = {
      region: config.get('region'),
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: config.get('key'),
        secretAccessKey: config.get('secret'),
      },
    };
    this.s3 = new MyS3Service(configuration);
  }
}
```

Inside the imported `MyS3Service` module there is a non-injectable class that looks like:

```js
export class MyS3Service {
  private client: S3Client; // this is AWS s3 v3 client, but doesn't matter
  constructor(configuration) {
    this.client = new S3Client(configuration);
  }

  async getListOfFiles() { ...some AWS S3 actions... }
}
```

So, I'm mocking it in a test with a helper function:

```js
export const S3ServiceMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    getListOfFiles: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 'OK' }))
  };
});
```

and the mock itself:

```js
jest.mock('../node_modules/@my-company/common', () => {
  const originalModules = jest.requireActual('../node_modules/@my-company/common');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModules,
    S3Service: S3ServiceMock,
  };
});
```

All requests to `MyS3Service` are successfully mocked and the data I need is being returned from these requests. However I can't spy on `MyS3Service` functions to get parameters that the functions were called with. Is it somehow achievable?

Comment: The only way I've found I can track the requests to my mocked functions - after tests I can get all data in `jest.mocked(MyS3Service).mock.results<...>`. There I've found the calls to function and call params

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  describe("MyS3Service", () => {
    const service = new MyS3Service({ ...configs});
    const myServiceSpy = service["client"];

    describe("when upload a file", () => {
      beforeAll(async () => {
         await service.{{ANYFUNCTION}}()
      })

      it("calls S3 funcion one time", () => {
        expect(myServiceSpy.{{ANYFUNCTION}}).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Every time the injectable service is created, the new instance of `MyS3Service` created. I've tried to make `myAwsService = module.get(MyAwsService)` and to get the `MyS3Service` from it, also I've put a `console.log(config)` in mocked `S3ServiceMock`. Then I've made `new MyS3Service(someOtherConfig)` and `MyS3Service` logged multiple times different configs